# an ansible deploy of an docker image throws port is already allocated

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ansible

I am a newbie to ansible and trying to convert my docker-compose file to 
ansible.yml.

I put the docker image of a dummy  flask app into my gitlab repository as mentioned in https://codebabel.com/ci-gitlabci-docker/.

I wrote a docker-decompose.yaml to run both the above image and elastic search and it's working fine.

```
  # Run both the app and Elasticsearch inside Docker containers.
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/bacdef/flaskapp:latest
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
    - elasticsearch
    links:
    - elasticsearch

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.0
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet

volumes:
  esdata01:
    driver: local

networks:
  esnet:
```

Then I tried to convert the same docker-compose.yml into **ansible.yml** as follows

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: "Elasticsearch"
      docker_container:
        name: "es01"
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.2.0
        ports:
          - "9200:9200"
        volumes:
          - "sdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data"
        env:
          node.name: es01
          cluster.initial_master_nodes: es01
          cluster.name: docker-cluster
          bootstrap.memory_lock: "true"

    - name: "Launch app container"
      docker_container:
        name: "app"
        image: registry.gitlab.com/bacdef/flaskapp:latest
        ports:
          - "5000:5000"
```

When I ran the above ansible file it fails with

> PLAY [localhost]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts]
>   ********************************************************* ok: [localhost]
>
> TASK [Elasticsearch]
>   *********************************************************** changed: [localhost]
>
> TASK [Launch app container]
>   **************************************************** fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error starting
>   container
>   380e56eb2d9579d407727b031713b056efda14f1a73fd9c88f65349567caa9f9: 500
>   Server Error: Internal Server Error (\"driver failed programming
>   external connectivity on endpoint app
>   (2020132c9cb503817740c063b1d231e3bb72e56d91a0386edd0cc6d23def992f):
>   Bind for 0.0.0.0:5000 failed: port is already allocated\")"}
>
> PLAY RECAP
>   ********************************************************************* localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0
>   failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

But I am sure that no other process is using the port 5000 other than this docker image. I ran `losof -i:5000` and killed the process which was running on this port before running `ansible-playbook ansible.yml`
 I could not find why the process is not able to bind to 5000.

Could someone please share some high level advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ansible tells you that the port is already in use, then it means that it is already in use.
Try to run `lsof` as root to find wich process is binded to your port :

```sh
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep 5000
```

Eventually, you can also check that you have no container running on this port (with a basic `docker container ls`)

Comment: I ran losof -i:5000 before running the ansible but not with sudo. I could try that but I am not expecting anything. I will let you know. I am sure that no other docker container is running. I removed all other containers.

Comment: I restarted the machine and it started working fine. I really do not know what happened. May be something else was running.Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, and since it shows up in search I'll add my workaround-type solution. The observed behaviour could just be erratic cache behaviour in docker. Try this on the host:

```
docker container prune
```

Since containers will be recreated in the next ansible run this should be safe to do. Pruning manually has helped me a couple of times.